# upload folder recursively with HTML5 drag and drop and FILE API

Tags: javascript, html

I've been surfing across the web for the last 2 hours reading about the possibility of uploading a folder recursively. It seems that it could be possible cross-browserly with HTML5's `drag & drop` and `File API`. However, I've read that `File API` standard is rejected and it will not become a standard. Yet all the latest versions of the major browsers support it with some differences. I need to implement the feature of uploading a folder on production website and I don't know whether I should proceed with it or tell my manager that it's currently impossible with pure JS. What to do? I might have missed something if so please tell.

Comment: Dont rely to much on official standards when developing JS. If it's supported in all your targeted browsers, just go for it.

Comment: Thanks, my fear is that since it's not going to be a standard browsers might decide to remove it from supported API.